# Nested while Loops is not working in python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, nested, cascade

My code is :-

```
n = 6
i = 0
j = 0
while(i < n):
    while(j<n):

        print(i,j)
        j += 1

    i += 1
```

and the output is:-

```
0 0

0 1

0 2

0 3

0 4

0 5
```

This code should run from 0 0 to 5 5 but its not Can someone please help me .....

Comment: You never reset j in the outer loop

Comment: Explain the code to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) (or suitable substitute).

Comment: I strongly recommend reading this article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 2):

you need to reset the j value after the first loop:

```
n = 6
i = 0
j = 0
while(i < n):
    j=0
    while(j<n):

        print(i,j)
        j += 1

    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much better to use if the task isn't excplicitly to use nested while loops

```
n = 6
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print(i, j)
```